# Need help solving $\int x \sqrt{\frac {a^2 - x^2} { a^2 + x^2 }} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have a complicated integral to solve. Can someone provide a better way to solve it than what i did - dividing by a inside the root, and then putting $ t = x / a $, and then putting $t^2 = \cos \theta $ and so many other substitutions.
$$
  \int x \sqrt{\frac {a^2 - x^2} { a^2 + x^2 }} dx
$$

Answer (score 4):

Let $x^2=a^2\cos(y)$. We then have $2xdx = -a^2 \sin(y) dy$. The integral then becomes
\begin{align}
I & = \int x \sqrt{\dfrac{a^2-x^2}{a^2+x^2}} dx = -\int \dfrac{a^2}2 \sin(y) \sqrt{\dfrac{1-\cos(y)}{1+\cos(y)}}dy = -\dfrac{a^2}2 \int \sin(y) \tan(y/2) dy\\
& = -a^2\int \sin^2(y/2)dy
\end{align}
I trust you can finish it from here.

Comment: @SriKrishna You might be slightly bothered by the different signs for the integral, but the limits will take care of the signs. So be careful with the limits.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the algebraic substitution:

$$t=\frac{a^{2}-x^{2}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}.\tag{0} $$

We have that

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int x\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}-x^{2}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}}dx=-\int \sqrt{t}\frac{a^{2}
}{\left( 1+t\right) ^{2}}dt\tag{1} \\
&=&a^{2}\frac{\sqrt{t}}{1+t}-a^{2}\arctan \sqrt{t}+C \\
&=&\frac{a^{2}+x^{2}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}-x^{2}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}}-a^{2}\arctan 
\sqrt{\frac{a^{2}-x^{2}}{a^{2}+x^{2}}}+C,
\end{eqnarray*}$$

because the integral in $t$ $(1)$ can be evaluated by using another algebraic substitution, $$u^{2}=t,\tag{2}$$ and expanding into partial fractions the resulting integrand
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{\sqrt{t}}{\left( 1+t\right) ^{2}}dt &=&2\int \frac{u^{2}}{\left(
1+u^{2}\right) ^{2}}\,du \\
&=&2\int -\frac{1}{\left( 1+u^{2}\right) ^{2}}+\frac{1}{1+u^{2}}\,du.\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$